# NSInternalInconsistencyException : must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

i know this question is already being asked so many times but i've gone through that questions but am not able to figure out whats actually wrong in my case

my error message :

```
    Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier PostCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1823f6db0 0x181a5bf80 0x1823f6c80 0x182d7c154 0x1876ddbf0 0x193b51ccc 0x10009b474 0x10009b50c 0x1878ab030 0x1878ab198 0x18789a298 0x1878afc64 0x1876408c4 0x1875501e4 0x184ee2994 0x184edd5d0 0x184edd490 0x184edcac0 0x184edc820 0x187552ff4 0x1823ad09c 0x1823acb30 0x1823aa830 0x1822d4c50 0x183bbc088 0x1875be088 0x10009aefc 0x181e728b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

here's my tableView with 5 static cells as you can see cell's identifier is already set to `PostCell` and the assigned class is `TableViewCell` 
[image]

`TableViewCell` class :

```
    class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

`tableViewController` Class :

```
class PostTableViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 5
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PostCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    return cell
}
}
```

this is so frustrating trying to figure from last night , if anybody knows whats wrong or what am missing then please let me know

Comment: You can't use static cells, but I presume you mean custom cell.  What have you specified for the reuse identifier on the next inspextor tab - the one with the slider icon?

Comment: slider icon ? @Paulw11 cell no. 2 ?

Comment: In the inspector on the right; at the top.

Comment: @Paulw11 man am not getting you

Comment: Having 5 cells with the same identifier makes me think you have done something wrong. In the object properties inspector on the right the reuse identifier for *one prototype cell* must be "PostCell"

Comment: okay at the right top there are 6 inspectors , which one you're talking about ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114399/discussion-between-paulw11-and-remy-boys).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to dequeue cell instances and modify them then you must use prototype cells, not static cells.  Also each cell must have a unique reuse identifier.